# Join same table mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm passing ID in the URL to productPage.php

in productPage.php :

`$ProductID = $_GET["ProductID"];` ( i.e Product-id = 1 )

Then I query the DB with ProductID to get the right product.

```
$sql = "select * from Products where id = '".$ProductID."' "


|     Id     |   Category  |     Type     |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
|     1      |    shoes    |       8      |
|     2      |  Underpants |       21     |
|     3      |    socks    |       4      |
|     4      |    shoes    |       8      |
|     5      |  flip flops |       11     |
|     6      |    shoes    |       34     |
```

So the Type value result for my query is 8
What should I do in order to get only the products with the same Type? (8)
do I have to use a second query?

Comment: "to get only the products with the same Type as my ProductID". In your example this should only be Product 1. Your question is not clear to me and I guess it isn't for other as well. Could you rephrase your problem clearly?

Comment: @Wimanicesir Looking at the table example, it would be Product 1 and 4. As they both have a Type of 8, which matches product 1.

Comment: @IncredibleHat, I see the difference but the question is wrong. "With the same type as my productID" So as in Anand his answer. The result wil ONLY BE product 1 and not product 4.

Comment: @Wimanicesir hm. I read it as "Get all products that have the same type as the single product I search for"... which Anand answer will return ALL products with Type 8 (which I think is what the asker wants?). So, yeah, guess the question is confusing us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it mandatory to use join?

You can use

```
select * from Products where Type = (select Type from Products where Id = :productId)
```

Simple enough to write.

Comment: Props for suggesting a placeholder with id, to suggest switching to parameterized queries for sql safety.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a sub query to get the desired `Category`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Products
WHERE
    Type = (
        SELECT
            Type
        FROM
            Products
        WHERE
            id = 1);
```

Comment: I didnt downvote this. But its the same answer already provided by Anand, except you had Category before the edit (and still do in the description). Yes, I'm very anal about things being right.

Comment: No worries, quality has to be maintained. When I posted my answer, I think both answers were posted about the same time, only difference was this answer had no typos in the table names (I modified it once more since it queried based on the Category name rather than the Type), weird why someone had the urge to downvote